# Word2Vec / Doc2Vec training fails: Supplied example count (0) did not equal expected count

Tags: gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I am learning Word2Vec and was trying to replicate a Word2Vec model from my textbook. Unlike what the textbook shows, however, my model gives a warning saying that `supplied example count (0) did not equal expected count (2381)`. Apparently, my model was not trained at all. The corpus I fed to the model was apparently an re-usable iterator (it was a list) as it passed this test:

```
>>> print(sum(1 for _ in corpus))
>>> print(sum(1 for _ in corpus))
>>> print(sum(1 for _ in corpus))

2381
2381
2381
```

I tried with gensim 3.6 and gensim 4.3, and both versions gave me the same warning. Here is a code snippet I used with gensim 3.6:

```
word2vec_model = Word2Vec(size = 300, window=5, min_count = 2, workers = -1)
word2vec_model.build_vocab(corpus)
word2vec_model.intersect_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz', lockf=1.0, binary=True)
word2vec_model.train(corpus, total_examples = word2vec_model.corpus_count, epochs = 15)
```

This is the warning message:

```
WARNING:gensim.models.base_any2vec:EPOCH - 1 : supplied example count (0) did not equal expected count (2381)
WARNING:gensim.models.base_any2vec:EPOCH - 2 : supplied example count (0) did not equal expected count (2381)
WARNING:gensim.models.base_any2vec:EPOCH - 3 : supplied example count (0) did not equal expected count (2381)
WARNING:gensim.models.base_any2vec:EPOCH - 4 : supplied example count (0) did not equal expected count (2381)
WARNING:gensim.models.base_any2vec:EPOCH - 5 : supplied example count (0) did not equal expected count (2381)
WARNING:gensim.models.base_any2vec:EPOCH - 6 : supplied example count (0) did not equal expected count (2381)
WARNING:gensim.models.base_any2vec:EPOCH - 7 : supplied example count (0) did not equal expected count (2381)
WARNING:gensim.models.base_any2vec:EPOCH - 8 : supplied example count (0) did not equal expected count (2381)
WARNING:gensim.models.base_any2vec:EPOCH - 9 : supplied example count (0) did not equal expected count (2381)
WARNING:gensim.models.base_any2vec:EPOCH - 10 : supplied example count (0) did not equal expected count (2381)
WARNING:gensim.models.base_any2vec:EPOCH - 11 : supplied example count (0) did not equal expected count (2381)
WARNING:gensim.models.base_any2vec:EPOCH - 12 : supplied example count (0) did not equal expected count (2381)
WARNING:gensim.models.base_any2vec:EPOCH - 13 : supplied example count (0) did not equal expected count (2381)
WARNING:gensim.models.base_any2vec:EPOCH - 14 : supplied example count (0) did not equal expected count (2381)
WARNING:gensim.models.base_any2vec:EPOCH - 15 : supplied example count (0) did not equal expected count (2381)
(0, 0)
```

I tried to train a different model with Doc2Vec with different corpus that is in the form of TaggedDocument, it gave me the same warning message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gensim's `Word2Vec` & `Doc2Vec` (& related models) don't take a `workers=-1` value. You have to set a specific count of worker threads.

Setting `-1` means no threads, and then the no-training situation you've observed. (There might be some better messaging of what's gone wrong in the latest Gensim or with loggin to at least the INFO level.)

Generally the `worker` count should never be higher than the number of CPU cores – but also, when training using a corpus iterable on a machine with more than 8 cores, optimal throughput is more likely to be reached in the 6-12 thread range than anything higher, because of some contention/bottlnecking in the single-reader-thread, fan-out-to-many-workers approach Gensim uses, and the Python "GIL".

Unfortunately, the exact best throughput value will vary based on your other parameters, especially `window` and `vector_size` and `negative`, and can only be found via trial-and-error. I often start with 6 on an 8-core machine, and 12 on any machine with 16 or more cores. (Another key tip is to make sure your corpus iterable is doing as little as possible – such as reading a pre-tokenized file from disk, rather than doing any other preprocessing every iteration, in the main thread.)

If you can get all your text from a pretokenized text file, you can also consider the `corpus_file` mode, which lets each worker read its own unique range of the file, and thus better achieves maximum throughput by setting workers to the number of cores.

Separate tips:

- A `min_count=2` value so low usually hurts word2vec results: rare words don't learn good representation for themselves from a small number of usage examples, but can in aggregate dilute/interfere-with other words. Discarding more rare words, as the size of the corpus allows, often improves all surviving words enough to improve overall downstream evaluations.
- `.intersect_word2vec_format()` is an advanced/experimental option with no sure best practices; try to understand what it does from the source code, and the weird ways it changes the usual SGD tradeoffs, before trying it – and be sure to run extra checks that it's doing what you want over more typical approaches.